# How to create function that reproduces other functions

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic exercise, but I cannot seem to find a way to reproduce a couple of functions inside of a function.

- **landscape(nf,sf,nm,sm)** receives number of flats, size of flats, number of mountains, size of mountains.
- **flat(sf)** - reproduces a set of sf number of underscores (_)
- **mountain(sm)** - reproduces a set of sm number of ', between /\
- **times(nf,nm)** - is supposed to reproduce nf and nm number of flats and mountains.

But times doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var landscape = function (nf, sf, nm, sm) {
    var result = "";
    var flat = function(sf) {
        for (var x = 0; x < sf; x++) {
            result += "_";
        }
    }
    
    var mountain = function(sm) {
        result += "/";
        for(var x = 0; x < sm; x++) {
            result += "'";
        }
        result += "\\";
    }
    

    var times = function(nf, nm) {
    // executes flat(nf) and mountain(sm)
        for (var z = 0; z < nf; z++) {
            flat(sf);
            for (var y = 0; y < nm; y++) {
                mountain(sm);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

console.log(landscape(2,3,2,3));
```

Comment: what are you doing wrong? What are you expecting and what is your output?

Comment: all you've done is declared `flat` and `mountain` and `times` but never invoked them.  Your result will always be `""` since you never invoke those functions.

Comment: landscape creates 3 functions, but never calls them. So this code looks to me like it would do nothing other than return an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the `times` function but you `return result;` before you execute it.

Add `times(nf, nm);` in before returning